# Import file from environment instead of read.table

Tags: r

I am using a package of someone else. As you see, there is a `ImportHistData` term in the function. I want to import the file from environment as `rainfall` name instead of `rainfall.txt`. When I replace `rainfall.txt` with `rainfall`, I got this error:

> Error in read.table(x, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, na.strings = y) : 
>   'file' must be a character string or connection

So, to import file not as a text, which way should I follow?

**Original shape of the function**

```
DisagSimul(TimeScale=1/4,BLpar=list(lambda=l,phi=f,kappa=k,
                                          alpha=a,v=v,mx=mx,sx=NA),CellIntensityProp=list(Weibull=FALSE,
                                                                                          iota=NA),RepetOpt=list(DistAllowed=0.1,FacLevel1Rep=20,MinLevel1Rep=50,
                                                                                                                 TotalRepAllowed=5000),NumOfSequences=10,Statistics=list(print=TRUE,plot=FALSE),
                 ExportSynthData=list(exp=TRUE,FileContent=c("AllDays"),file="15min.txt"),
                 ImportHistData=list("rainfall.txt",na.values="NA",FileContent=c("AllDays"),
                                     DaysPerSeason=length(rainfall$Day)),PlotHyetographs=FALSE,RandSeed=5)
```

**Source of ImportHistData part in the function**

```
ImportHistDataFun(mode = 1, x = ImportHistData$file, 
                     y = ImportHistData$na.values, z = ImportHistData$FileContent[1], 
                     w = TRUE, s = ImportHistData$DaysPerSeason, timescale = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check documentation of the package and see if the method (`?DisagSimul`) allows a data frame in memory to be used for *ImportHistData* argument instead of reading from an external .txt file.

If the function is set up to only read a file from disk and you do not want to save your *rainfall* data frame permanently as a file, consider using a `tempfile` that exists only in the R session or until you use `unlink()`:

```
# INITIALIZE TEMP FILE
tf <- tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".txt")    

# EXPORT rainfall to FILE
write.table(rainfall, tf, row.names=FALSE)    
...

# USE TEMPFILE IN METHOD   
DisagSimul(...
           ImportHistData = list(tf, na.values="NA", FileContent=c("AllDays"),
```